# How can $A \subset B \subset \overline{A}$

Tags: general-topology

I was trying reading Tammo Tom Dieck's *Algebraic Topology* when in proposition 2.1.2

> Let $(A_j | j \in J)$ be a family of connected subsets of X such that $A_i \cap A_j \neq \phi$ where $\phi$ is the empty set for all i,j. Then $\bigcup_j A_j = Y$ is connected. Let A be connected and **$ A \subset B \subset \overline{A}$**

I am having trouble with the last line a question on [stack exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3278353/another-way-to-show-a-subseteq-b-then-overlinea-subseteq-b-when-b-is-cl)  states that $A \subseteq B$ implies $\overline{A} \subseteq B$. But this does not seem to be the case here how is this possible?

Comment: This implication holds only when $B$ is closed.

Comment: Supporting the answer to this question, look at this example: $\left( 0, 1 \right) \subset \left[ 0, 1 \right) \subset \left[ 0, 1 \right] = \overline{\left( 0, 1 \right)}$.

Comment: Can we have open sets with such property I can't think of an example

Comment: Yes you can, but not in $\Bbb{R}$, at least, not if you want $A$ to remain connected. Take, for example, the open disc $B((0, 0); 1)$ in $\Bbb{R}^2$, and remove $\{(0, 0)\}$. Then the closure is still the closed disc $B[(0, 0); 1]$, and the set is open, so$$B((0, 0); 1) \setminus \{(0, 0)\} \subset B((0, 0); 1) \subset B[(0, 0); 1].$$

Answer (score 1):

For the post that you linked to, $B$ is closed.

Hence for such a $B$ to exists such that $A \subset B \subset \bar{A}$, $B$ is not closed.

Comment: @AdityaEkbote No, of course not.